# Checkbox Column in extjs Grid

Tags: extjs

I have  a grid which has 2 check-box columns.

For example(To, CC) check-box  in a grid when ever i check To check box all details in  that row should be placed in 'To' text field and same way which ever row is selected with 'CC' check-box all details  should be placed in another cc field  so my question how i can get checkbox value to separated those rows data based on selection

Comment: Created to chained stores one for To and one for CC and filter the records by the checkbox value. For more info check the ExtJS docs on ChainedStores

Comment: How do i can get checkbox value in extjs.. if possible can somebody provide snippet for checkbox  return values

Comment: The checkbox column has to have a dedicated field in the store. When it is changed the field is changed in the store.